# Empty circles with errorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I make a python plot with empty circles and error bars? I see I can use `facecolors='none'` for a scatter plot, but it is not working for errorbar plot. I also found `mfc='none'` which makes the circles empty, but the error bars are still visible inside the circles. How can I make it such that the circles are completely empty, and the error bars come out only from outside of the circles (the errorbars are bigger than the size of the data points)?Thank you!

Comment: You mean actual values? That is not relevant, for example a data point can be (10,10) and the errorbar on x and y can be 2 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to plot with `mfc` the same color with the background color, e.g. `mfc='w'`:

```
y = [1,2,3,4]
yerr=[.1,.2,.3,.4]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.errorbar(x=y,y=y, yerr=yerr, ms=30, marker='o', mfc='w')
```

Output:

[image]

However, there is a risk as you can see above, when the marker size is larger than the error, you don't get to see the error bars.

Comment: Actually I need them to be transparent. The main reason why I want to do this is because  I have multiple points overlap so this solution would still hide the points behind.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `mfc` as the background color is easy when the background is white. A more general solution is as follows:

```
y = [1,2,3,4]
yerr=[.1,.2,.3,.4]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
(plotline, _, _) = plt.errorbar(x=y,y=y, yerr=yerr, ms=30, marker='o', )
plotline.set_markerfacecolor('none')
plotline.set_markeredgewidth(0.5)
```

[image]